# Java Send mail javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException

Tags: java, email

I know there's couple of questions already exist about this 
but I tried them literally all , and still have the same error

I have java web application runing on ubuntu (VPS) in tomcat 7

I installed postfix as SMTP ( correct me if I'm wrong)

```
public class SendMail {

   public void send(String user){

       final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(SendMail.class);
      // Recipient's email ID needs to be mentioned.
      String to = "myemail@gmail.com";


      String from = "root@mydomain";



      String host = "mydomain";

      // Get system properties
      Properties properties = System.getProperties();

      // Setup mail server
      properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", host);
      properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
      properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.port", "587");


      // Get the default Session object.
      Session session = Session.getInstance(properties);

      try {
         // Create a default MimeMessage object.
         MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);

         // Set From: header field of the header.
         message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));

         // Set To: header field of the header.
         message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(to));

         // Set Subject: header field
         message.setSubject("This is the Subject Line!");

         // Now set the actual message
         message.setText(text);

         // Send message
         Transport.send(message);
         System.out.println("Sent message successfully....");
      } catch (MessagingException mex) {
          logger.error("This is error : "+mex);
         mex.printStackTrace();
      }
   }
}
```

Error from tomcat logs

```
javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException
        at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:306)
        at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:156)
        at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:105)
        at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:168)
        at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:98)
        at seminair.SendMail.send(SendMail.java:55)
        at seminair.UserInfo.getDefaultUserInJSON(UserInfo.java:18)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory$1.invoke(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:81)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:151)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:171)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$VoidOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:136)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:104)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:367)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:349)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:106)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:259)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:318)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:236)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:983)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:361)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:372)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:335)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:218)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:110)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:506)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:962)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:445)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1115)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:637)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:318)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I saw that in some examples they put username & password , but I'm not sure this is the credential for what exactly?

Comment: Common SMTP servers require an authentication before you can send an email.

Answer (score 0):

```
Session session = Session.getInstance(properties,
          new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                return new PasswordAuthentication(<username>, <password>);
            }
          });
```

Comment: can you please tell what's the username & password ??

Comment: The username and password of your email - root@mydomain

Comment: root@mydomain is the mail set while installing postfix , but there wasn't a password for that ( at least I didn't set one )

Comment: or should I use a real email like something@gmail.com ??

Comment: That would be a more viable option. Create a email account like no-reply@gmail.com and use that to send the email. 
In case of gmail do set the properties like :

props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
  props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");

Comment: I just tried you suggestion , didn't work same error

Answer (score 0):

per the stacktrace, you should get the source code of seminair at :

> ```
>     at seminair.SendMail.send(SendMail.java:55)
>     at seminair.UserInfo.getDefaultUserInJSON(UserInfo.java:18)
> ```

maybe getDefaultUserInJSON defaults to a wrong username or password

also as a general rule don't do :

> logger.error("This is error : "+mex); mex.printStackTrace();

instead do :

> logger.error("This is error : ", mex);